# Do we need responsive units like rem in modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I know responsive units like rem were introduced to make a page properly zoomable, but I wonder if there is **any other use case**, if modern browsers zoom px-based values, too? They even treat px-based media queries responsively nowadays: if I zoom into a responsive website far enough, it will switch to the mobile layout.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I only know one use case myself: If you want users to set the font-size dynamically on a page (e.g. like in a ebook reader app something like [this](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/larger-text-iphone.jpg)).

Answer (score 4):

`rem` was not introduced to make a page "properly zoomable", it was introduced to allow the sizes of things to be set relative to the base font size.

Having content scale based around the font size the user is comfortable reading is useful.

Comment: But you could already do that by using `medium` for a font size. That also switches back to the root font size.

Comment: @MrLister — (a) That only works for font sizes, not for anything else. (b) That only gives you 7 different sizes to play with.

Comment: a) OK. but b) all you needed to do was add some extra markup. `<div style="font-size: medium"><div style="font-size: 1.5em">` Voila, `1.5rem`!

Comment: And if you wanted to set the width then  you'd end up with something like: `<div style="font-size: medium"><div style="width: 20em"><div style="font-size: 1.5em;">`. Elegant and maintainable that is not.

Comment: By the way, seriously now, I just tested, and `medium` gives different results for monospace than `1rem`. Browser defaults usually have a smaller default size for monospace than for other fonts, so `medium` is smaller than `1rem` in those cases.